# Can't access to Iterator from derived class

Tags: c++

In summary, my problem is that I want to find a way to get an access to the element to which iterator is pointing from a derived class. The details are at the below.

I am implementing a sequence with a doubly linked list, referring to the book "Data Structures & Algorithms in C++" (written by Goodrich, Tamassia, Mount), page 255. The book defines class NodeSequence as a derived class of doubly linked list.

Here is the code. Firstly, I made a doubly linked list class with struct Node and class Iterator inside. (This is saved as "DList.h")

```
typedef int E;

class DList {
private:
struct Node {
    E element;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
};

public:
    class Iterator {
    public:
        E& operator*();//reference to the element
        bool operator==(const Iterator& p) const;
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& p) const;
        Iterator& operator++();
        Iterator& operator--();
        friend class DList; //gives access to the DList
    private:
        Node* v; //pointer to the node
        Iterator(Node* u); //create from Node
};

public:
    DList();
    int size() const;
    bool empty() const;
    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;
    void insertFront(const E& e);
    void insertBack(const E& e);
    void insert(const Iterator& p, const E& e);
    void eraseFront();
    void eraseBack();
    void erase(const Iterator& p);
    void printList(); 

private:
    int n;
    Node* header;
    Node* trailer;
};
```

Next, I made a derived class of DList named "NodeSequence", which is defined as the following

```
#include "DList.h"
class NodeSequence : public DList{ //NodeSequence class inherits DList class
public:
    Iterator atIndex(int i) const ; //get position from index 
    int indexOf(const Iterator& p) const; //get index from position
};
```

Finally, I wanted to test my code, so I demonstrated as the following.

```
int main() {
    NodeSequence test;
    test.insertBack(5);
    test.insertBack(4);
    test.insertBack(3);
    test.insertBack(2);
    test.insertBack(1);

NodeSequence::Iterator p= test.atIndex(1);
cout << (p.v)->element() << endl; 
// I expected 4, but it gives compile error, it says I can't access to p.v because it is a private member
```

}

Is there any way I can get an access to the private element (which is a pointer) of the iterator? I do not want to change Node* v from private to public.

Comment: Why don't you use the dereferencing `operator*()` operator you declared in your iterator class?

Comment: Well you could grab the address of the ref returned by the `*` operator, seems a bit pointless though, why do you want the raw pointer?

Comment: Oh, I'm such a fool... thanks...@user0042